# Moq - mocking ILog.InfoFormat without checking every args

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

I'm unit testing around some logging we have in place

Underneath the MyLoggingMethod (extension method) in my code example log.InfoFormat should be called with loads of parameters.  I don't care how many parameters are passed in - or the contents - I just want to verify somethings logged from the first parameter.

I've made up the It.IsAnyLoadOfParameters - but that's what I'm trying to achieve!

```
        var logMock = new Mock<ILog>();
        var log = logMock.Object;
        log.MyLoggingMethod(new Monkey());
        logMock.Verify(moqLog => moqLog.InfoFormat(It.Is<string>(x => x.Contains("Blah blah blah")), It.IsAnyLoadOfParameters));
```

and the kind of thing that would be within log.MyLoggingMethod would be

```
log.InfoFormat("Blah blah blah {0} {1} {2} {3}", 1, "something", "blah", "four");
```

I know I can put lots of It.IsAny - but I want to avoid that if possible.  I just want to check the first one to make sure something's there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
It.IsAny<object[]>()
```

did the trick!

```
    var logMock = new Mock<ILog>();
    var log = logMock.Object;
    log.MyLoggingMethod(new Monkey());
    logMock.Verify(moqLog => moqLog.InfoFormat(It.Is<string>(x => x.Contains("Blah blah blah")),  It.IsAny<object[]>()));
```

Comment: To be more speficic: It.IsAny(`object[]`) did the trick since the signature is probably `InfoFormat(string format, params `object[]` args)`